# DOM event chaining not working

Tags: javascript, dom, chaining

So, any hints why this is not working?
I'm trying to get both input fields ('pagamento' and 'parcelas') at a preset if the 'Boleto' radiobox is selected, ('1' and 'MercadoPago', respectively, and back again to user input if the 'Cartão' radiobox is selected.

```js
function boleto() {
    if(document.getElementById('tipodepagamento').checked==true){
        document.getElementById('pagamento').value = 'MercadoPago';
        document.getElementById('pagamento').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('parcelas').value = '1';
        document.getElementById('parcelas').disabled = true;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('pagamento').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('parcelas').disabled = false;
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="tipodeconta" id="tipodepagamento2" value="Cartão" checked onClick="boleto();">Cartão de Crédito
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="tipodeconta" id="tipodepagamento" value="Boleto" onClick="boleto();">Boleto
    </label>
</div>
<label>Plataforma de Pagamento</label>
<select class="form-control" onClick="fpagamento();validador();" onKeyUp="fpagamento();" name="pagamento" id="pagamento">
    <option value="Selecione">Selecione</option>
    <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
    <option value="MercadoPago">Mercado Pago</option>
</select>
<label>Número de Parcelas</label>
<select class="form-control" id="parcelas" name="parcelas">
    <option value="1">1x</option>
    <option value="2">2x</option>
</select>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('pagamento').value = 'MercadoPago';
   document.getElementById('pagamento').value = '1'; you are setting same field twice here. i think second line you need to set value for parcelas.

Comment: Could you add your `html` code too?

Comment: When is `boleto` executed? You may be running/binding the function before the DOM exists.

Comment: add you `html` and `event trigger`.

Comment: It would be easier for us to answer if you added your `html` as well.

Comment: This code has syntax error - `}}` at the end. So it will not work,

Comment: Would you accept a JQuery answer?

Comment: yes, i'm running jQ 1.12.3 on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle = http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#d692f9461c022ee386cb2c5329f453c4

I see a few problems with your code.

```
<input type="radio" name="tipodeconta" id="tipodepagamento" value="Boleto" onClick="boleto();">
<select class="form-control" onClick="fpagamento();validador();" onKeyUp="fpagamento();"
```

First off you shouldn't use `onClick` for a radio button, or a `select` element. use `onChange` instead which means you won't need to call `onKeyUp="fpagamento();"`

**BTW**: your code is very [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). In addition it's bad practice to add a onClick attribute in your html (same goes for other events). Put your javascript in a .js file and edit it there.

```js
var tipodeconta = $('input[name=tipodeconta]'),
    cartao      = document.querySelector('#tipodepagamento2'),
    pagamento   = $('#pagamento'),
    checkThis   = $('.form-control');

tipodeconta.on('change', function() {
  if (cartao.checked) {
    pagamento.val('MercadoPago');
  }
  (cartao.checked) ? checkThis.prop('disabled', true) : checkThis.removeAttr('disabled');
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="tipodeconta" id="tipodepagamento2" value="Cartão" checked=""> 
        Cartão de Crédito
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="tipodeconta" id="tipodepagamento" value="Boleto">
        Boleto
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<label>Plataforma de Pagamento</label>
<select class="form-control" name="pagamento" id="pagamento" disabled="">
  <option value="Selecione">Selecione</option>
  <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
  <option value="MercadoPago">Mercado Pago</option>
</select>
<label>Número de Parcelas</label>
<select class="form-control" id="parcelas" name="parcelas" disabled="">
  <option value="1">1x</option>
  <option value="2">2x</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The thing is that when 'Boleto' is selected both 'pagamento' and 'parcela' must be disabled, and 'Cartão' must be selectable